# add/remove elements to array with checkboks and reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs, checkbox

I have this code that inserts the ids of the checkboks into an array, but if I disable them, it does not remove them, i use update to react-addons-update
any suggestions

```
     constructor(props) {
        super(props);
         this.state={
           keyGen:[]
         }
      }
      render(){  
         <form> 
            {this.renderElements()}
             <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </form>
      renderElement(){
       return this.props.Elements.map((item, index)=>{
render(
        <Input name='list' type='checkbox' onClick={()=>this.updateStateList(item.id)} label='Add' className='listTour' />
       ) 
        })
        }

      updateStateList(value){
        this.setState(update(this.state, {keyGen: {$push:[value]}}))
        console.log(this.state.keyGen)
      }
```

thanks

Comment: if you uncheck the checkbox, it doesn't remove the items from the array?

Comment: no, only insert items

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "if I disable them"?

Comment: The idea is that when doing uncheck, remove the id from that checkbocks in the array

Comment: Just use `array.filter()` in the updateStateList method to return the array without the Id. First you check if the Id that was just clicked is present in the array via `array.some()`. If it is present, use `array.filter()` to filter the array out and set `keyGen` equal to the filtered array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

// modify render function like this.

You can see the working code here http://codepen.io/umgupta/pen/dNVoBg
See console tab at the bottom

```
    class UpdateStateDemo extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={keyGen:[]} 
      }

      render(){ 
        console.log(this.state)
        return (
        <form>
            {
              this.props.Elements.map((item, index)=>{  
                return (
                  <input 
                    key={item} 
                    name='list' 
                    type='checkbox' 
                    onClick={(e)=>this.updateStateList(e,item)}
                    label='Add' 
                    className='listTour' />
                ) 
             })  
            }
          <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </form>
        )
      }

  updateStateList(e, value){
    console.log(e.target.checked)
    if (e.target.checked){
      //append to array
      this.setState({
        keyGen: this.state.keyGen.concat([value])
      })
    } else {
      //remove from array
      this.setState({
        keyGen : this.state.keyGen.filter(function(val) {return val!==value})
      })
   }
}
}
```

Comment: It works thanks, but it's funny why when I do the first select it shows me the empty array you know why it can be

Comment: Because you have an empty array set in state?

Comment: But if the user sends only one data, then send the empty array, how could solve it

Comment: @FERNANDOORTIZ See the working code pen link. I could not make your code work as is. So I have modified. I hope, I haven't changed the original problem.

Comment: I tried many different stack overflow posts and solutions, I felt I could understand nearly all of them, but none of the them worked for, none of them removed the value from the arrary, but yours works, and its also simple cheers

Comment: @AndrewIrwin Thanks (especially for the appreciation)! I am glad that you found it helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I can finally move onto the next thing, so much of my time was being taken up before I came across your solution. I have one question though, how can I dynamically set the names of state keys i.e `this.setState({[dynamicKey: this.state.[dynamicKey.concat([value])]})`

Comment: @AndrewIrwin I am not sure I understand your problem, you want to concat to some dynamic key?

Comment: its ok, I got it. I was trying to dynamically get one of the items in the state object. I aksed a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54129355/how-to-dynamically-get-state-array-name-react/54129418#54129418 and got an answer! :)