# How to dynamically get state array name React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state-management, react-state

How can I dynamically set the name of the array in state, to get it from state.

```
onCheckBoxItemClickList(e, value, path) {
    console.log(e.target.checked)
    if (e.target.checked) {
        //append to array
        this.setState({
            [path]: this.state.[path].concat([value])
        })
    } else {
        //remove from array
        this.setState({
            [path]: this.state.[path].filter(function (val) {
                return val !== value
            })
        })
    }
}
```

I know how to dynamically set and get a key in state, but when I 
try and do

`[path]: this.state.[path].concat([value])`

I get the below error:

[image: error Image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an extra dot in your code (after state):

```
[path]: this.state.[path].concat([value])
```

Should be:

```
[path]: this.state[path].concat([value])
```

Then whenever you want to set the state based on the previous state, you should use the `setState` which takes a callback in, with the `prevState` as argument.

So your code should look something like:

```
onCheckBoxItemClickList(e, value, path) {
    console.log(e.target.checked)
    if (e.target.checked) {
        //append to array
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            [path]: prevState[path].concat([value])
        }))
    } else {
        //remove from array
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            [path]: prevState[path].filter(function (val) {
                return val !== value
            })
        }))
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers thanks very much. It's a bit confusing that if you want to specify the array name/state key (not dynamically) it requires the dot beforehand, but doing it dynamically doesnt require the dot. This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43985409/2208342  on stack overflow made state a lot clearer to me and showed me that state is an object.